# HighRes image crop tool (not Aviary plugin)

Tags: plugins, image

Is there an alternative to the Aviary plugin (https://github.com/fruitstudios/AviaryImageEditor)?

I only need to be able to offer the client a visual interface for cropping (in 1 aspect ratio only). 
While Aviary works great, it's limited at the moment to low res images and I really need high res images as I use them full screen.

Does anyone know an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While its pretty basic right now, we've just added this to [Image Resizer](https://github.com/engram-design/ImageResizer), which can get you off to a great start - even if you need to extend it to your specific needs!

Comment: Read it yesterday on twitter. Looks great! Will definitely try it! Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Aviary is pretty heavy handed. I agree with you, it'd be great to have some tools in Craft to handle cropping. There's been some rumblings in the past of Craft 3 shipping with some new toys but that's a ways away. I don't know of any alternative but you could certainly build your own.

Use something like [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html) then use some tools server side to crop the actual image. That's relatively straightforward.

Implementing it in Craft is the other tricky piece. Wonder if anyone else in the Craft community has tried doing something like this?